# Parameter specified as non-null is null error in Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey
    @Json(name = "id") val userId: String,
    @Json(name = "login") val userName: String,
    @Json(name = "avatar_url") val userAvatar: String,
    val profile: Profile? = null
) : Serializable
```

Here is my Profile data class

```
data class Profile(
    val avatar_url: String,
    val bio: String,
    val blog: String,
    val company: Any,
    val created_at: String,
    val email: Any,
    val events_url: String,
    val followers: Int,
    val followers_url: String,
    val following: Int,
    val following_url: String,
    val gists_url: String,
    val gravatar_id: String,
    val hireable: Boolean,
    val html_url: String,
    val id: Int,
    val location: String,
    val login: String,
    val name: String,
    val node_id: String,
    val organizations_url: String,
    val public_gists: Int,
    val public_repos: Int,
    val received_events_url: String,
    val repos_url: String,
    val site_admin: Boolean,
    val starred_url: String,
    val subscriptions_url: String,
    val twitter_username: Any,
    val type: String,
    val updated_at: String,
    val url: String
) : Serializable
```

but every time I try to insert data into the table I am getting the error, how can I insert null data object in table while using room database?

Comment: could you show what data is being inserted?

Comment: No data is inserted, its giving that error!

Comment: Paste your Profile class in the question

Comment: Edited and given the Profile Class @KaruneshPalekar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that Room doesn't know how to insert attribute of type **Profile** to the table.

The simple solution would be to use a type converter. Something like the following:

```
class DatabaseConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toProfile(profileJson: String): Profile? {
        return <Create a Profile object out of a JSON string>
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromProfile(profile: Profile?): String {
        return <JSON string representation of Profile object>
    }
}
```

In your case - you can use "" (empty string) when Profile is null.

More info about converters: [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)

Comment: In my case data type Profile is null initially, I want to update it later, but I am unable to insert null "Profile" data in the table

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Edited my answer.

Comment: Hey after your edited answer, my problem solved! Thanks a lot I was just missing a '?' in the fromProfile() method :)